# Hibernate query causing error 181 on DB2 for Dates

Tags: hibernate, jpa, db2

I am using Hibernate 4 on DB2 v9 with JPA 2's CriteriaBuilder to build a query on the fly that can filter by date. The relevant part of the predicate is...

```
criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(myRoot.get(MyEntity_.myDate), aDateValue)
```

My mapping is pretty straight forward...

```
@Column(name="MY_DATE")
@Temporal(value = TemporalType.DATE)
public Date getMyDate() {
    return myDate;
}
```

The column on the table is of type `DATE`. The error I get when I run a query with this restriction is...

> org.hibernate.exception.DataException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-181, SQLSTATE=22007

If I take the generated SQL and run it in a stand alone SQL editor, it runs fines. I have tried changing to `TemporalType.TIMESTAMP` with no luck. I have double-checked that the bind input is valid at runtime as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that if `aDateValue` is of type `java.sql.Date` rather than `java.util.Date` the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that worked for me was to add

`@Type(type = "date")`

to the java.util.Date field in the entity. It seems that Hibernate maps the type java.util.Date with a Sql Timestamp while when the Type annotation is added it is maped as Date